# How to scroll down in a particular section of webpage in selenium using javascript executor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I am aware that we can use the below to scroll down on the webpage.

```
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
```

But I have a particular section in the webpage, which has a scroll bar.
I need to go to the last element in that section. Problem is the last element's locator will not be found until and unless I scroll down completely.
How do we handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution provided by @Guy and it doesn't seem to work.

Alternatively, you can find the section as an WebElement using the classname or xpath and then scroll passing that element as follows:

```java
WebElement sectionToScroll = driver.findElement(By.className("main-body-container"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 500)", sectionToScroll);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `scrollBy` on the `WebElement` you want to scroll

```
WebElement toScroll = driver.findElement(...)`
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 1000)", toScroll);
```

No need to cast to `JavascriptExecutor`, `WebDriver` already extends this class.